# How to create a laravel model that implements an API?

Tags: api, model, laravel

When I create a Model, it initially looks something like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';
 ....
  .. etc
```

The problem is, it connect to a DB. I want a way that it skips the fact that I want it to connect to a DB, but rather allow me to overwrite the functions like this:

```
function find($id) {
    //insert curl api call to get user id
}
```

How does one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override them all:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public static function find($id, $columns = array('*')) {
        //insert curl api call to get user id

       return $model;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can replace the `static` method with `scopeFind($q, $id, $columns = array('*')) { return $q->... }`, hope you know that but you didn't use butt you could have and better IMO.